# JMXTools sources

Tags: java, jmx

I have expired problems using jmx tools(

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.sun.jdmk.comm.HtmlAdaptorServer.setParser(HtmlAdaptorServer.java:232)

)
I use jmxtools-1.2.1.jar.
To investigate problem I need jmx tools sources(jmxtools-1.2.1-sources.jar) 
But I can not find such all over th internet =(
Please help me to understand NullPointerException or download sources

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The project home-site for this is [OpenDMK](http://opendmk.java.net).

Their source code is in [java.net's Subversion repository](http://java.net/projects/opendmk/sources/svn/show).

I have posted a mavenized version of that sub-project [here](https://github.com/nickman/OpenDMK/tree/master/OpenDMK/core/).

The source for that specific class in the mavenized project is [here](https://github.com/nickman/OpenDMK/blob/master/OpenDMK/core/src/main/java/com/sun/jdmk/comm/HtmlAdaptorServer.java).